# setOpacity for multiple markers at the time

Tags: leaflet, markers

I'm using leaflet for my project and I want to use filter marker in it. To do it, I will setOpacity to 0 for all markers and re setOpacity to 1 for my targets. I know leaflet allow to setOpacity for each market but can I set all markers at the same time?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that

**In leaftlet**

Create a layer group and add each marker to this group :

```
var myGroup = L.layerGroup([mark1, mark2, ...]);
```

You can add the entire group to the map.

Then, when you want to set marker opacity to 0 do :

```
myGroup.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    layer.setOpacity(0);
});
```

A little jsfiddle example here :

https://jsfiddle.net/csblo/64phqLb7/4/

**In pure javascript**

Store all your markers in an array. First create an array :

```
var allMarkers = [];
```

And when you create a new marker push it in this array :

```
var marker = L.marker(...);
allMarkers.push(marker);
```

Then, when you have to set opacity to 0 :

```
allMarkers.forEach(function(marker) {
    marker.setOpacity(0);
});
```

Comment: I tried pure, just with the setIcon() function JS variation (even before I saw this forum, so I started to dig up) and it did not worked for me... I get error: marker.setOpacity is not a function ...

Comment: @la_femme_it Dobrý den, maybe "marker" object is not actually a marker type ?

Comment: it is. It did worked with leaflet built in functions :) Might be Zeppelin specific issue, I do not know. Javascript is waaay out of my league. Hezky den