# Is there a way to modify opacity for existing markers/shapes in leaflet for R (with shiny)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

This might be a silly question. I have a map embedded in a shiny app and I am looking for a way to programatically adjust opacity of a marker/shape or groups of those, after they have been added to the leaflet map with `addMarkers(...)`  or similar `add*` function. Potentially, the same principle could also apply for other marker parameters, but opacity is my first goal.

Javascript leaflet seems like it allows it, judging per this thread: [setOpacity for multiple markers at the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43339457/setopacity-for-multiple-markers-at-the-time)

The JSFiddle code in the answer seems to allow exactly that, by accessing each layer under a given group and setting its opacity via `layer.setOpacity()`.

below is a minimal setup for such a shiny app:

**ui.R:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    leafletOutput("maptest"),
    sliderInput(inputId = "opacity.slider", label = "opacity", min = 0, max = 1, value = 1)
  )
)
```

**server.R:**

```
server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$maptest <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addMarkers(lat = c(0), lng = c(0), layerId = "layer1", group = "testgroup")
  })

  observeEvent(input$opacity.slider, {
    print(input$opacity.slider)
    leafletProxy("maptest") %>% setGroupOpacity(group = "testgroup", opacity = input$opacity.slider)
  })
}
```

The `setGroupOpacity` function in the the observer that monitors events on the slider is not yet implemented anywhere: I'm looking for a way to implement such a function.

Is there anyway to achieve this in R? Possibly throwing some javascript in there...

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a simple self-contained example.  You're much more likely to get answers - even useful answers - if you do so.

Comment: @Limey I have included a minimal dashboard example that best describes the functionality I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, comeas.

I can't help you with your problem directly: I'm not familar enough with `leaflet`, alas.  However, a little Googling gave me the `leaflet.opacity` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaflet.opacity/vignettes/leaflet-opacity.html).  It strikes me that this, combined with `shinyjs` - in particular [extendShinyjs](https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/extend) - should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think ```leaflet.opacity``` achieves what I'm looking for: it adds a control layer (slider) which allows the user the control opacity of a given layer. What I am after is to control this server side. In the example it is done inside an observer, but the opacity update should be possible using any condition, via ```leafletProxy```.