# R leaflet in Shiny, layer opacity controled by sliderInput

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet, opacity

I am developing a shiny app with leaflet and several added polygons, and I want to control the polygons opacity with a `sliderInput()`.

I have a working solution that restart `addPolygons()` when the opacity is changed but that's not elegant since the polygons are "re-drew" instead of just the opacity changed.

There are plenty of code snippets that create an opacity slider in the leaflet but I am unable to adapt the code to input from my `sliderInput()` instead of an `addControl()`.

Could someone help?

Here is my working but not elegant solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview) #to get the franconia dataset
library(htmltools)

colors <- colorFactor(palette = c("Red", "Green", "Blue"),
                      levels = c("Oberfranken","Mittelfranken", "Unterfranken"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(
        inputId = "opacity_sliderinput", label = NULL, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1, 
        value = 1, ticks = FALSE 
      )
    ), ## End sidebarPanel
    
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("my_map", width = "100%", height = "100vh")
    )
    
  ) ## End sidebarLayout
)## End fluidPage

##
## Server ######################################################################
##

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$my_map = renderLeaflet({
    
    leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", group = "CartoDB.Positron")
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$opacity_sliderinput, {
    
    leafletProxy("my_map") %>%
      clearGroup("Districts") %>%
      addPolygons(data = franconia, fillColor = ~colors(district), weight =  1, group = "Districts",
                  fillOpacity = input$opacity_sliderinput
      )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Examples that I am trying to adapt:

[Add opacity slider in R leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662029/add-opacity-slider-in-r-leaflet)

Similar Question with no accepted answer:

[Is there a way to modify opacity for existing markers/shapes in leaflet for R (with shiny)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61945093/is-there-a-way-to-modify-opacity-for-existing-markers-shapes-in-leaflet-for-r-w)

And here trying to use javascript but not working (i need to get rid of the `addControl()` and have the `onRender()` take input$opacity_sliderinput):

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview) #to get the franconia dataset
library(htmltools)

colors <- colorFactor(palette = c("Red", "Green", "Blue"),
                      levels = c("Oberfranken","Mittelfranken", "Unterfranken"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(
          inputId = "opacity_sliderinput", label = NULL, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1, 
          value = 1, ticks = FALSE 
        )
      ), ## End sidebarPanel
    
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("my_map", width = "100%", height = "100vh")
    )
    
  ) ## End sidebarLayout
)## End fluidPage


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$my_map = renderLeaflet({
    
    franconia %>% leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", group = "CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
      addPolygons(fillColor = ~colors(district),weight =  1, group = "Districts") %>%
      addPolygons(label = ~NAME_ASCI,weight =  1, group = "Names", fillColor = "Grey") %>%
      addLayersControl(baseGroups = "CartoDB.Positron",overlayGroups = c("Districts", "Names"),position = "topleft")
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$opacity_sliderinput, {
    
    leafletProxy("my_map") %>%
      
      removeControl("opacity_slide") %>%
      addControl(layerId = "opacity_slide", html = "<input id=\"OpacitySlide\" type=\"range\" min=\"0\" max=\"1\" step=\"0.1\" value=\"0.5\">") %>%   # Add Slider
      htmlwidgets::onRender(
        "function(el,x,data){
                     var map = this;
                     var evthandler = function(e){
                        var layers = map.layerManager.getVisibleGroups();
                        console.log('VisibleGroups: ', layers); 
                        console.log('Target value: ', +e.target.value);
                        layers.forEach(function(group) {
                          var layer = map.layerManager._byGroup[group];
                          console.log('currently processing: ', group);
                          Object.keys(layer).forEach(function(el){
                            if(layer[el] instanceof L.Polygon){;
                            console.log('Change opacity of: ', group, el);
                             layer[el].setStyle({fillOpacity:+e.target.value});
                            }
                          });
                          
                        })
                     };
              $('#OpacitySlide').mousedown(function () { map.dragging.disable(); });
              $('#OpacitySlide').mouseup(function () { map.dragging.enable(); });
              $('#OpacitySlide').on('input', evthandler)}
          ")
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you had an `opacity_slide`  define inside of the map and another `opacity_sliderinput` slider defined in shiny. In the code below, I got rid of leaflet's input that is defined.

Furthermore, there is no need to define the `htmlwidgets::onRender` call within a `observeEvent`. I believe this will simply cause the function to be re-registered multiple times whenever the slider is changed which is undesirable.

Instead, in the code below we register the `onRender` once when creating the map. I also removed the second `addPolygon` call since all this was doing was adding labels, this can be moved into a single addPolygonCall. It was also drawing the same set of polygons twice, once with colors, and a second time Gray.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview) #to get the franconia dataset
library(htmltools)

colors <- colorFactor(palette = c("Red", "Green", "Blue"),
                      levels = c("Oberfranken","Mittelfranken", "Unterfranken"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(
        inputId = "opacity_sliderinput", label = NULL, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1, 
        value = 1, ticks = FALSE 
      )
    ), ## End sidebarPanel
    
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("my_map", width = "100%", height = "100vh")
    )
    
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$my_map = renderLeaflet({
    
    franconia %>% leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", group = "CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
      addPolygons(fillColor = ~colors(district), fillOpacity = 1, weight =  1, group = "Districts", label = ~NAME_ASCI) %>%
      addLayersControl(baseGroups = "CartoDB.Positron",overlayGroups = c("Districts", "Names"),position = "topleft") %>%
      htmlwidgets::onRender(
        "function(el,x,data){
                     var map = this;
                     var evthandler = function(e){
                        console.log('hello world');
                        var layers = map.layerManager.getVisibleGroups();
                        console.log('VisibleGroups: ', layers); 
                        console.log('Target value: ', +e.value);
                        layers.forEach(function(group) {
                          var layer = map.layerManager._byGroup[group];
                          console.log('currently processing: ', group);
                          Object.keys(layer).forEach(function(el){
                            if(layer[el] instanceof L.Polygon){;
                            console.log('Change opacity of: ', group, el);
                             layer[el].setStyle({fillOpacity:+e.value});
                            }
                          });
                          
                        })
                     };
              $('#opacity_sliderinput').on('shiny:inputchanged', evthandler)}
          ")
  })
  
  

  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works on my real case app. The post's app was a minimum reproducing example, the 2nd `addPolygons()` for names was just to create a second group "Names" (see the `addLayerControls()` call). In my case the slider and leaflet are in a shiny module and i could make it work by adding the module id in the last line of `onRender()`: `$('#module_id-opacity_sliderinput').on('shiny:inputchanged', evthandler)}`